# Contact form 7 добавление кода PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте под управлением Wordpress есть форма сделана c помощью плагина Contact Form 7.
Как добавить во входящий имейл из формы еще функцию get_page_link()
Мне нужно знать из какой страницы была отправлена форма.
Помогите, а =)

Comment: А много страниц?

Comment: Такая форма находится на 26 разных страницах..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в форму письма такой шорткод: `[_url]`.

Есть целый набор [специальных шорткодов](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/), которые помогут вывести в теле письма дату, время, название поста, его ID, характеристики сайта и т.д.

Comment: Круто. Спасибо большое за наводку на документацию.

Comment: Это не только ссылка на документацию, но и полноценный ответ на ваш вопрос. Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.